# Create a new table (multiple columns) by selecting random values from an existing table

Tags: postgresql, update, table, cte, random

I am stuck on the following task (PostgreSQL 9.3). Let's say we have the following table1 (which has 10k rows):

table1:

```
id
754
800
330
4
59
```

My goal is to create another table2 with two columns (source, target), where the values of both columns are a random selection of table1.id values. For example:

table2:

```
source | target
754    | 59
4      | 4
59     | 330
```

This is what I've done:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  source integer,
  target integer,
  distance double precision
);

-- Select 300 table1.id values and insertion into table2.source  
INSERT INTO table2(source)
SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 300;

-- Select 300 table1.id values and updating table2.target 
UPDATE table2 SET target = i.id
FROM (SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 300) i;
```

I got the following result:

```
source | target
754    | 59
330    | 59
800    | 59
```

Unfortunately all the `table2.target` values are all the same. How can I update `table2.target` with different random values (like in the example) ? Or maybe `UPDATE` is not the good way for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a ["data-modifying CTE"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT id
      FROM   tbl
      ORDER  BY random()
      LIMIT  600  -- 2 x 300
      ) sub
   )
INSERT INTO table2(source, target)
SELECT c1.id, c2.id
FROM   cte c1
JOIN   cte c2 ON c2.rn = c1.rn + 300;
```

In the CTE:

1. select 600 random rows (to create 300 new rows)
2. add a row number in the outer SELECT.

Then couple two values in a self join with 300 offset.

To get random rows from a huge table cheaply, consider:
[Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)

Comment: Hello Erwin ! Thanks a lot for your answer. Your solution works great. I learned from it.

Comment: Another idea would be to add `random() AS rnd` in the subquery, add `LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY rnd) AS lagid` in the cte and then use `INSERT ... SELECT id, lagid FROM cte WHEN rn % 2 = 0;`